# Convert iso 8601 timestamps to unix timestamp in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, function, date, scripting

I have a script that receives all kinds of different data arrays from a web based API.  That program returns all dates in the ISO 8601 format (2013-08-12T09:00:00:000-0600).  I have a function that will convert those easily to a unix timestamp, but I have to submit the value field to that function each time which can become tedious.

The trick is, depending on what operation I am running at the time, the response array from the web app will be very different.  Single dimensions and multidimensional.  There are also numerous key names for the date holders.

So, is there some way to easily submit a full array of data to a function that will seek out the ISO timestamps and convert them to a unix timestamp in-place, returning the same array with the swapped out timestamps?

Here is the function I use to convert them one at a time:

```
function tstamptotime($tstamp)
{
    // converts ISODATE to unix date
    // 1984-09-01T14:21:31Z
    sscanf($tstamp, "%u-%u-%uT%u:%u:%uZ", $year, $month, $day, $hour, $min, $sec);
    $newtstamp = mktime($hour, $min, $sec, $month, $day, $year);
    return $newtstamp;
}
```

Here is what I had come up with, but I realized that this idea would not take into account multidimensional arrays, and the trick is that the array could be anywhere from 2-25 levels deep:

```
foreach($results['data'] as $key => $value) {
            if(strpos($key,'Date') !== false) {
                if(strlen($value) == 28) {
                    $results['data'][$key] = tstamptotime($value);
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see, the key of the value will always contain the word "Date" as part of the key name.

If it helps, the "results['data']" array in my example comes from a json string where I use json_encode to create the array.  So I do have all values in plain text as well if something can be done there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = $results['data'];
array_walk_recursive($res, function (&$e, $k){
    if(strpos($k, 'Date') !== false) {
        if(strlen($e) == 28) {
            sscanf($e, "%u-%u-%uT%u:%u:%uZ", $year, $month, $day, $hour, $min, $sec);
            $e = mktime($hour, $min, $sec, $month, $day, $year);
        }
    }
});
$results['data'] = $res;
```

Since I don't know what your data looks like, I used the following to test:

```
$results['info'] = array('some','info','here');
$results['data'][] = array('Date1' => '2013-08-09T09:00:00:000-0600');
$results['data'][] = array('Date2' => '2013-08-10T09:30:00:000-0600');
$results['data'][] = array('Date3' => '2013-08-11T09:45:00:000-0600');
$results['data'][] = array('Date4' => '2013-08-12T10:05:00:000-0600');
$results['data']['nested'][] = array('Date1' => '2013-08-09T09:00:00:000-0600');
$results['data']['nested'][] = array('Date2' => '2013-08-10T09:30:00:000-0600');
$results['data']['nested'][] = array('Date3' => '2013-08-11T09:45:00:000-0600');
$results['data']['nested'][] = array('Date4' => '2013-08-12T10:05:00:000-0600');
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [info] => Array(
            [0] => some
            [1] => info
            [2] => here
        )
    [data] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [Date1] => 1376049600
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [Date2] => 1376137800
                )
            [2] => Array(
                    [Date3] => 1376225100
                )
            [3] => Array(
                    [Date4] => 1376312700
                )
            [nested] => Array(
                    [0] => Array(
                            [Date1] => 1376049600
                        )
                    [1] => Array(
                            [Date2] => 1376137800
                        )
                    [2] => Array(
                            [Date3] => 1376225100
                        )
                    [3] => Array(
                            [Date4] => 1376312700
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Close.  It walks through the array and performs the time convert, but it never stores the new number back into the array, overwriting the ISO timestamp.

If I echo "$e" it's the right timestamp, just need to figure out how to make it replace the ISO timestamp.

Comment: @Josh - I don't know exactly what you mean, but I fixed a couple typos and updated my answer with sample data. Can you clarify what you mean by overwriting the tiemstamp?

Comment: Yeah, I found the typo.  Perhaps it's the fact that it's almost 1am, but I redid it and it's working.  Awesome!  Thanks!